# PhantomJSDriver maven dependency causes "internal java compiler error"

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using [`Selenium`](https://www.seleniumhq.org) with `maven`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-alpha-1</version>
</dependency>
```

and when I added the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I started getting a Java compiler error:

```
Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
```

I'm using `IntelliJ IDEA`. Is there a way I can debug this problem? What might be the cause?

Comment: @Guy: Yes, there is. See this maven dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/4.0.0-alpha-1

Comment: PhantomJS is deprecated and will not work with Selenium 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomJS is supported until Selenium version 3.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Using [an older `Selenium`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59) version worked.